# awk group by column and sum multiple value

Tags: awk

i'm trying to grouping by "name" and sum values columns "qty" and "price", a sample data like this:

> ```
> names,fruits,qty,price
> tom,banana,2,500
> tom,banana,3,750
> tom,apple,2,500
> alex,banana,3,750
> alex,melon,3,750
> alex,melon,3,750
> jess,banana,1,250
> jess,banana,1,250
> jess,banana,1,250
> danny,melon,2,500
> danny,apple,2,500
> danny,apple,2,500
> ```

i already try using this commands:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
            NR==1{print; next} 
            {
                q=$3; 
                $3="~";
                w=$4; 
                $4="~";
                a[$0]+=q;
                b[$0]+=w
            } 
       END  {
                for(k in a) 
                {
                    sub("~",a[k],k); 
                    sub("~",b[k],k);
                    print k
                }
            }' file
```

with that command, i got empty in "price" column, and my desired output is like this :

> ```
> names,fruits,qty,price
> alex,banana,3,750
> tom,banana,5,1250
> alex,melon,6,1500
> jess,banana,3,750
> danny,apple,4,1000
> danny,melon,2,500
> tom,apple,2,500
> ```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: i try to find solution on another web before and got similar problem, in that thread they used ~ for Substituting with value of SUMMED.

Comment: The requirements make no sense. You cannot add together the quantities of different products, like bananas and apples.  Quantity gets multiplied by the product unit price, to calculate the cost, and the cost can then be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
 NR==1{ print; next }
 { key=($1 OFS $2) }
 { grpByQty[key]+=$3; grpByPrice[key]+=$4 }
END{ for(key in grpByQty) print key, grpByQty[key], grpByPrice[key] }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
    print $0
    next
}

NR > 1 {
    ori = price[$1 "," $2]
    if (ori == "") {
        price[$1 "," $2] = $3 "," $4
    } else {
        split(ori, a, ",")
        price[$1 "," $2] = a[1] + $3 "," a[2] + $4
    }
}

END {
    for (name in price) {
        print name, price[name]
    }
}
```

The idea is to store `name` concatenated with "," and `fruit` as key with `quantity` concatenated with "," and `price` as value.